# How to handle common data in microservices

Tags: database-design, architecture, microservices, grpc, event-driven

I'm new to microservices architecture, and trying to figure out how to communicate between services.

For example, I have some type codes that I need to share between services, such as device type codes, company type codes, and I manage these codes in ServiceA.

If a user needs to create a record in ServiceB and some fields in this record will refer to these codes, and I want to check if these codes are correct, should I call ServiceA through a synchronization method, such as gRPC?

When these codes changed, I also need to notify other services via Event bus. Is it reasonable to have Event bus and gRPC in the same architecture? Or what is a better way to do it?

Comment: In a microservice architecture, a piece of data is owned by only one microservice. So, you may want to revisit your microservices breakup, if you need multiple microservices to validate the same data.

Answer (score 0):

although yours it's a somewhat common scenario, it's recommended to design microservices around DDD aggregates. This way it's unlikely to be in a cross-service situation like you are right now.

That being said, let's go through the various cases:

1. create a record in ServiceB: I'd make a few changes here. First of all, make ServiceB "private" and prevent external clients to call it. Don't have too much logic in it, just the bare minimum (eg. local invariants validation). Then create an "orchestrator" service. This one will be responsible for cross-services validation (eg. calling ServiceA to check the codes) and eventually call ServiceB to perform the write. Communication between the Orchestrator and the services can be through gRPC.
2. code changes: use an integration event and a topic system (like Azure Service Bus for example). Then have the Orchestrator subscribe to it and react accordingly.